# How to open a dialog center-screen or center-owner?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dialog

I have a MVVM application and I have a main viewmodel. In this model I use the following code to open a dialog:

```
dlgViewModel myDlgViewModel = new dlgViewModel();
dlgView myDlgView = new dlgView();
myDlgView.DataContext = myDlgViewModel;
myDlgView.Owner = App.Current.MainWindow;
myDlgView.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
myDlgView.ShowDialog();
```

Also, in the XAML on my dlgView, I set the WIndowsStartupLocation to CenterOwner. However the window does not open in the center of the owner. I tried CenterScreeen but that does not work either.

How can I open a new view using the centerOwner or centerScreen option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the first time thing is set in the axml of my dialog WindowsStartUpLocation to center owner.

Then, in the main view model, I use this code:

```
dlgViewModel myDlgViewModel = new dlgViewModel();
dlgView myDlgView = new dlgView();
myDlgView.DataContext = miDlgViewModel;
myDlgView.Owner = App.Current.MainWindow;
myDlgView.ShowDialog();
```